# SOLR UI - How can I add multiple values in facet.query?

Tags: solr, facet

I am using Solr Admin and I want to facet specific values in facet.query. I was successful on faceting it by typing in HTTP but I still want to do it simply in Admin page UI.

**For example:**

> localhost:8389/solr/core-abc/select?q=*:*&facet=true&facet.query=name:abc&facet.query=name:def&facet.query=name:ghi

[image]

So, What should I do in Admin page? Sorry for my English. Thanks advance.

Comment: you need to mention the value "name:abc" in the box against the facet.query and mention the facet.field ans name

Comment: @AbhijitBashetti I only use syntax "name:abc" for 1 value, but for my problems, it use for multiple value. For example name:abc, name:def, name:ghi......

Comment: Delete the : between q= &facet 
`localhost:8389/solr/core-abc/select?q=&facet=true&facet.query=name:abc&facet.query=name:def&facet.query=name:ghi`

Comment: It's 2024 and for Solr 9.4 I posted a solution here https://stackoverflow.com/a/78093392/1412906